# Fading with limited colors

Tags: graphics, colors

How do you make a nice fade from white to black with a limited set of colors?

I'm writing a "demo" for virtual machine i have designed and written. It has 4096 colors and i need to do a nice fade from white to black. Since there is only 16 different levels of gray i would like to extend this by using some more colors.

I have seen nice fades from white to black on the c64 using far fewer colors.

Is there any general function for doing this in arbitrary color spaces.?

Comment: Are the 4096 colors fixed?

Comment: Yes. First four bits is blue. The second four bits is green and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the brightness of the available colors:

RGB:  brightness = (R + G + B) / 3

Or use other color models (HSL, HSV etc.): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space#Lightness

and order the colors by brightness.

If you are free to generate any color, create/generate a nice palette of colors and, again, order by brightness.

Comment: One could additionally restrict the saturation/chroma/colorfulness in the selection to have less colorful temporary impressions. (E.g. only those with `max(R,G,B) - min(R,G,B) < Threshold`).

Comment: @Trilarion - Yes, also the choice to use Brightness is arbitrary. Anything that orders colors is valid. There is no definite definition of 'nice fade'. So anything goes :)

Comment: I ended up only using the 16 shades of gray. To use an ordered list of colors would not have looked good.http://imgur.com/dWHg2SL

Comment: Sure, the 'nice fade' requirement, requires taste. And that is something we don't have at SO. (Or rather: we don't want to fight about that)